# In Jmeter getting a blank/null response for maximum of the samplers, how can I overcome it?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I have a script in which I have 30 to 40 http samplers and say for sampler number 10 I'm getting like 80% samplers response as blank or null, due to which rest of the samplers below it are also getting impacted as the result of variable not getting extracted in the post processor.
The response time at the 90th% for the 10th sampler is around 25sec.
I want to know is there any thing which I can do in the script to avoid this blank issue or is it something which app server is sending as the result of not able to bear the load.
Will changing the response timeout in the HTTP request default to higher value say 5 Min will resolve the issue?
Please help
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [Extractor Success Assertion](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-extract-success) plugin which checks whether the variable(s) declared in the PostProcessor(s) still have(s) default value(s) and if nothing has been extracted - it fails the relevant Sampler.

So you could use any other "Action to be taken after a Sampler error" than `Continue` in your [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to decide whether you want to start new iteration or stop the thread/test when the response is blank.

[image]

Extractor Success Assertion plugin can be installed (and kept up-to-date) using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)